# Ionic show image from camera and gallery in app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to use the [camera Cordova plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/camera/) to show an image taken from camera or picked from the device inside the app.

using [this project as a guideline](https://github.com/BenjaminGHo/ionic-image-upload)
my code:

to install plugin:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/camera@4
```

**in html file**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Hello Ionic</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
<h3 text-center>
  {{imageSrc}}
</h3>
<div class="gallery-button" text-center>
  <img [src]="imageSrc" />    
</div>

</ion-content>
```

**in ts file**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';

.
.
.
.

private imageSrc: string;

getImage() {
let cameraOptions = {
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,      
      quality: 100,
      targetWidth: 1000,
      targetHeight: 1000,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,      
      correctOrientation: true
    }
    console.log(cameraOptions);
    this.camera.getPicture(cameraOptions)
      .then(file_uri => this.imageSrc = file_uri, 
      err => console.log(err));   
  }

}
```

the issue is the image is not shown in my view and get a broken image icon in its place like below. All examples I've seen use similar code and they all have this problem of broken image link instead of the actual image being shown.

[image: issue]

Comment: That project you are using as a guide is for Ionic4 which is quite different to Ionic3 which you seem to be trying to target. (AKA not a good guide for your requirements)

Answer (score 3):

You can use @ionic-native/file-path node module to resolve the file path as below:
basically, If we are selecting an image from PHOTO LIBRARY then we have to resolve the path to get the correct file path.

This is what I have used:

```
  // Get the data of an image
        this.camera.getPicture({
            quality: 60,
            sourceType: sourceType,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
            encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
            correctOrientation: true  //Corrects Android orientation quirks
        }).then((imagePath: string) => {

            // Special handling for Android
            if ((this.platform.is('android') || this.platform.is('Android')) && sourceType === this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY) {

                this.filePath.resolveNativePath(imagePath)
                    .then((filePath: string) => {

                        let correctPath: string = filePath.substr(0, filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                        let currentName: string = filePath.substr(filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                        console.log('currentName', currentName);
                        console.log('correctPath', correctPath);

                    }).catch((ex: string) => {

                    });

            } else {
                let currentName: string = imagePath.substr(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                let correctPath: string = imagePath.substr(0, imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

            }
        }, (error: any) => {


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install additional modules to solve this issue, you can use the preinstalled cordova-plugin-ionic-webview plugin as follows:

after import lines, add this line so that TypeScript won't complain

```
declare var window;
```

instead of this

```
this.imageSrc = file_uri
```

use this

```
 this.imageSrc = window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(file_uri)
```

Then rerun your project and it should work properly as shown below

[image]

Note: Make sure you're using cordova-plugin-ionic-webview>2.0.